# Taking logarithm and multiplying dataframe columns

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a DataFrama like this:

```
K   T   
0   24
1   76 
2   88
```

and want to multiply the natural logarithm of K by T and save in new column G.

**My attempt**

Naming `df` to the dataframe, then:

```
df['G']=df['T']*np.log(df['K'], np.e)
```

but get this error:

```
TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType
```

I know that the way I took natural logarithm can be wrong but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Well, there is always the [Numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html)

Comment: I have read that @MrT and couldn't understand the problem. The docs say the base must be specified and I got confused.

Comment: `base` is imho only specified for the [`math.log` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/math.html#math.log) Don't confuse them - math is for scalars, numpy for arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to specify `np.e`, which seems to be your issue.  The default for [`np.log`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html) is already the natural log.

```
>>> df['T'] * np.log(df['K'])
0       -inf
1     0.0000
2    60.9970
dtype: float64
```

In your call, `np.e` gets interpreted as the `out` parameter, which isn't an array.  Hence, "return arrays must be of ArrayType."